# SQL Server Management Studio 2008 Express installation

Tags: sql-server-2008

Is it possible to install SQL Server Management Studio 2008 Express without installing the SQL Server 2008?  I have now the SQL Server 2005 and SQL Server Management Studio 2005 Express on my computer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should be able to just choose the management tools when running through the installer.  It also looks like you can download SSMS directly from [here](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=08E52AC2-1D62-45F6-9A4A-4B76A8564A2B&displaylang=en).